# 'cat file' stdout differs from 'cat file > textfile'

Tags: linux, email, redirect, cat

When I cat my aws backup data (gathered with $(aws s3 sync   >> logfile)  the data looks good when I 'cat' the file, but if I 'grep yada yada|sed yada yada backup.log > newfile', then pipe that to 'mail' or look at it with 'vi', it has extra characters now shown in stdout.  An example:

[cat to stdout]

```
$ cat aws.tail.log
Starting aws backup Wed Apr 17 00:01:01 EDT 2019

upload: zim/Beer/.zim/state.conf to s3://...
upload: Documents/testfile to s3://...



Completed  aws backup Wed Apr 17 00:01:52 EDT 2019
```

[cat redirect to file]

```
$ cat aws.tail.log > aws.email.txt
$ vi aws.email.txt  

here's what I see in vi:

Starting aws backup Wed Apr 17 00:01:01 EDT 2019
Completed 0 file(s) with ~0 file(s) remaining (calculating...)^M                                                              
Completed 2.5 KiB/~225.5 KiB (14.8 KiB/s) with ~3 file(s) remaining (calculating...)^Mupload: zim/Beer/.zim/state.conf to s3://
Completed 2.5 KiB/~225.5 KiB (14.8 KiB/s) with ~2 file(s) remaining (calculating...)^MCompleted 3.5 KiB/~225.5 KiB (3.5 KiB/s) with ~2 file(s) remaining (calculating...) ^Mupload: zim/Beer/h
ouse/tech/sterling/notifications.txt to s3://
Completed 226.1 KiB/~226.1 KiB (70.3 KiB/s) with ~0 file(s) remaining (calculating...)^M                                                                                      
Completed 0 file(s) with ~0 file(s) remaining (calculating...)^MCompleted 0 file(s) with ~0 file(s) remaining (calculating...)^MCompleted 0 file(s) with ~0 file(s) remaining (calculating...)
^MCompleted 0 file(s) with ~0 file(s) remaining (calculating...)^MCompleted 0 file(s) with ~0 file(s) remaining (calculating...)^MCompleted 0 file(s) with ~0 file(s) remaining (calculating..
.)^MCompleted 0 file(s) with ~0 file(s) remaining (calculating...)^MCompleted 0 file(s) with ~0 file(s) remaining (calculating...)^MCompleted 0 file(s) with ~0 file(s) remaining (calculating
...)^MCompleted 0 file(s) with ~0 file(s) remaining (calculating...)^M
```

This is also showing up in the email body when I email with $(cat daily_stats.txt |mail -s "subject" $EMAIL), or also using $(mail -s "subject" $EMAIL

I have tried filtering out the ^M characters, but it does only that.  Also tried:
    sed -r "s/\x1B[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g"
and
    perl -p -e 's/\r//g'

and still, the extra lines (Completed 0 file(s) with ~0 file(s) remaining (calculating...)^M)

Anyone know how to get the stdout I see from 'cat' into an email or a text file without the extra jazz?

Thanks!

Comment: There's no great way to do this. You should instead disable progress and formatting in `aws s3 sync` in the first place, e.g. with `--no-progress` and/or `--color off` . The fact that it doesn't do this automatically when stdout is a file is a bug on their side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
cat aws.tail.log | col -b > aws.email.txt
```

I'd recommend filing a bug against the tool writing this log about autodetecting non-terminal and not using control characters.